# Android nestedscrollview not triggering nested fling

Tags: android-recyclerview, behavior, android-coordinatorlayout, nestedscrollview

I'm using nestedscrollview in sliding card to pull it up and down, by  extending coordinator layout behavior class and overriding its nested scrolling and flinging methods.

In my layout, I have on recylerview, and two nestedscroll view one to wrap the header and make it pull the card up and down, and one for the to wrap and error message which appears after any error message.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/slidinguppanel_slidingcontainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:background="@android:color/white">

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?actionBarSize"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/blocking_error_panel"
        layout="@layout/blocking_error_panel" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/choose_bus_headers"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageButton
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_publicbus_choosebus_bus" />

                        <com.wrzit.app.Utils.CustomTextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtPanelHeader"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/toolbar_text_margin_start"
                            android:text="@string/bus_panel_header_text"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/card_header_text_size"
                            app:typeface="roboto_regular.ttf" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/btnSlider"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="end"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_expand_more_white_24dp" />

                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


            <com.wrzit.app.Utils.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/txtGPSNotification"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/notification_background"
                android:padding="@dimen/notification_padding"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/regular_text_size"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:typeface="roboto_regular.ttf" />

            <com.wrzit.app.Utils.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/txtNetworkNotification"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/notification_background"
                android:padding="@dimen/notification_padding"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/regular_text_size"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:typeface="roboto_regular.ttf" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progress"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"
                android:indeterminate="true"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutFilterBusStop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtFilterBusStopName"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Jalan Raja Chulan"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:singleLine="true" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:text="Filtered Bus Stop" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/btnFilterBusStopClose"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center|right"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp" />

                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/listChooseBus"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="#E7E8E7"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The behavior detects triggers onNestedPreFling() when I fling the recyclerview, or the nestedscrollview that wraps the header. The problem occurs when I fling the nestedscrollview that wraps the error layout, it triggers onNestedPreScroll(), but doesn't always triggers onNestedPreFling(), even though scroll amount larger than the touch slop.

I tried to identify what cause this issue, but unfortunately was not able to identify it. hopefully someone knows what prevents onNestedPreFling() from being called.

Comment: There is currently no support for passing nested flings in the nested scrolling implementation. I have submitted a patch to aosp which adds nested fling. Unfortunately the 23.2 (and 23.3) code has not yet been pushed yet by google, so it is currently based on 23.1.1. check out comments [#79](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=177729#c79) and [#85](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=177729#c85)